# Responsive Menu Flashes On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting reports from users that when they click the 3 line mobile menu of their phone, the menu won't stay open, it'll just flash and disappear. It happens on iOS and Android phones.

http://samiconcepts.com/xidax-home (this is the site with the issue).

Can anyone assist on this, I have no idea how to solve it :/ Thank you

```js
(function($, undefined) {
  var open = [];

  var opts = {
    selector: '.dro

    pdown ',
    toggle: 'menuR1',
    open: 'dropdown-open',
    nest: true
  };

  $(document).on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown', function(e) {
    // Close the last open dropdown if click is from outside the target dropdown
    if (open.length && (!opts.nest || !open[open.length - 1].find(e.target).length)) {
      open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
    }

    var $this = $(e.target);

    // If target is a dropdown then toggle it...
    if ($this.hasClass(opts.toggle)) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $this = $this.closest(opts.selector);

      if (!$this.hasClass(opts.open)) {
        open.push($this.addClass(opts.open));
      } else {
        open.pop().removeClass(opts.open);
      }
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdown {
  FONT-SIZE: 12PX;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f2f2f;
}


/* toggle */

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #fff;
}


/* options */

.dropdown-menu .option a {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  text-align: center;
}

.respMenu {
  display: block;
}

.header2 {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-menu .option a:hover {
  background-color: #02bc00;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}


/* open */

.dropdown-open {
  z-index: 400;
}

.dropdown-open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header2">

  <a href="/"><img src="/images-xidax/logo-white.png" class="logoR"></a>

  <div id="language" class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="/images-sumo/list-menu.png" class="menuR1"></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="option"><a href="/">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li class="option"><a href="/">REVIEWS</a></li>
      <li class="option"><a href="/">FINANCING</a></li>
      <li class="option"><a href="/">COMPANY</a></li>
      <li class="option"><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li class="option"><a href="/">CART</a></li>


    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any relief from it if the JS is moved to the bottom of the page, before the end of the body?

Comment: http://samiconcepts.com/xidax-test (This link has the code on the bottom, I can't replicate the issue from my phone because it's working fine even though other phone users experience the issue. By any chance does the first links menu I sent not work, and this one work for you on mobile?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that touchstart and click bring issues when on the same element at the same time. So the touchstart will trigger a click which will make the menu flash.

You can however check, if current device is a touch device and only add the needed event (either touch *or* click):

I modified your JS on three lines providing that:

```
(function($, undefined)
       {
           var open = [];

           var opts = {
               selector: '.dropdown',
           toggle: 'menuR1',
           open: 'dropdown-open',
           nest: true
       };

       var clickEvent = (function() {
         if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement === true)
         return 'touchstart';
         else
         return 'click';
       })();

       var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement === true;
       var dropdownEvent = isTouchDevice ? 'touchstart.dropdown' : 'click.dropdown';

       $(document).on(dropdownEvent, function(e)
       {
           // Close the last open dropdown if click is from outside the target dropdown
           if ( open.length && ( ! opts.nest || ! open[ open.length - 1 ].find( e.target ).length ) )
           {
               open.pop().removeClass( opts.open );
           }

           var $this = $(e.target);

           // If target is a dropdown then toggle it...
           if ( $this.hasClass( opts.toggle ) )
           {
               e.preventDefault();

               $this = $this.closest( opts.selector );

               if ( ! $this.hasClass( opts.open ) )
               {
                   open.push( $this.addClass( opts.open ) );
               }
               else
               {
                   open.pop().removeClass( opts.open );
               }
           }
       });

   })(jQuery);
```

You might be able to reproduce the issues on chrome, by opening the [mobile view](https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop).

**Edit**
* I fixed a syntax error I copied from above code.
* Take care to refresh browser after switching mobile and desktop view in Chrome, so that correct event is used on initializing the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I put the code, but now the 3 line menu simply does nothing when you click it, both on desktop/mobile

Comment: Also, yes I can now replicate on mobile view...by any chance so you have a fix for this?

Comment: I found the solution! From the original jQuery code, if I just remove touchstart.dropdown, it works :)

Comment: Sure, as mentioned, having both events at the same time brings issues. I edited above code example. You might still use it, as click event on mobile will now only trigger when releasing, with touch start it will be triggered directly which might be a benefit for your mobile user experience.

Comment: Thank you again for your help marvhock, I appreciate it